# Extent Reports generating two HTML Reports

Tags: c#, extentreports

so I've worked with Extent Reports several times in the past versions (Since 2.0 upwards) and I was able to generate a single html report after tests were executed, same happened on version 3.0 until version 4.0 which generates dashboard.html and index.html.

From a Business perspective it is a bit weird having two report files... am I missing something on my code, or is that the new Standard of the Reporting stuff?

Single report file is generated on both versions 2.X and 3.X of ExtentReports
For both Java/C#

Attached you can see the actual code I'm using on version 3.1 to get a single file report

```
_extent = new ExtentReports();
var dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Replace("\\bin\\Debug", "");
DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(dir + "\\Test_Execution_Reports");
var htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(@"C:\testR\AutoReport.html");
htmlReporter.LoadConfig("C:\\testR\\ReportConfig.xml");
_extent.AddSystemInfo("Environment", "Test Report");
_extent.AddSystemInfo("User Name", "Test User");
_extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following resolved the issue.

I was previously using

```
ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(reportPath);
```

in v4 I am using the following (basically this creates v3 style report on v4)

```
ExtentV3HtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentV3HtmlReporter(reportPath);
```

so please replace ExtentHtmlReporter with ExtentV3HtmlReporter

```
var htmlReporter = new ExtentV3HtmlReporter (@"C:\testR\AutoReport.html");
```

Comment: Thanks @SuC. Worked properly! Quite weird as why the changes on the new version though

Comment: Glad it helped you.

Comment: Whether this will help to generate single report for multiple test categories ?

Comment: I want the reverse of it. I want two report file index and dashboard .html while I am getting only 1 . how can I achieve this ? I am using extentReport4
ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(path);