# How to keep history of all execution in ExtentReports version 4?

Tags: c#, selenium, extentreports

How can I keep reports for each of the execution/run in ExtentReports Dashboard using version 4. It is overwriting the previous run details.

I am currently using :

```
Selenium WebDriver,
C#,
VS2019,
Specflow &
ExtentReports version4
```

Though, I am able to accomplish this using KLOV and MongoDB. I am not able to share the reports with other stakeholders as they don't have the required set up to access the report.

Before posting this question, obviously I have gone through these below mentioned links but could not find a proper solution

1. [Extent Reports V4 overwriting test results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54237310/extent-reports-v4-overwriting-test-results)
2. [How can I append existing reports in ExtentReports 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57033956/how-can-i-append-existing-reports-in-extentreports-4)

Used 'ExtentV3HtmlReporter' but only got a new report ExtentReport.html, so currently there are 3 different files

1. dashboard.html
2. ExtentReport.html
3. index.html

Selenium & C#:

```
[BeforeTestRun]
    public static void InitialSetUp(IObjectContainer objectContainer)
    {
        //Initialize Extent report before test starts
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        var dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Replace("\\bin\\Debug", "");
        DirectoryInfo diretcoryInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(dir + "\\TestReports");
        var htmlReporter = new ExtentV3HtmlReporter(dir + "\\TestReports" + "\\ExtentReport" + ".html");
        htmlReporter.Config.Theme = AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter.Configuration.Theme.Standard;
        extent.AddSystemInfo("Environment", "QA");
        extent.AddSystemInfo("Host Name", System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());
        extent.AddSystemInfo("OS Info", System.Environment.OSVersion.ToString());
        extent.AddSystemInfo("Browser", "Chrome");
        extent.AddSystemInfo("Username", System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

        //klov server set up
        //klovReporter = new ExtentKlovReporter();
        //klovReporter.InitMongoDbConnection("localhost", *****);
        //klovReporter.ProjectName = "*******";
        //klovReporter.ReportName = "UI Automation Report";
        //klovReporter.InitKlovServerConnection("http://localhost");

        //extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter, klovReporter);
        extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);
    }
```

Unable to get historical reports in ExtentReports version 4. Getting the report for the last executed test/build.

Comment: How about creating a unique folder when you are running the suite every time ?

Answer (score 0):

use class `ExtentV3HtmlReporter htmlReport = new ExtentHtmlReporter(DirectoryPath)` in V4 Extent Report.